# Problems displaying repetitive items in the List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Please this is my first post here and I am very new to ASP MVC 5. I have been on this issue for 2 days but i could not just find the solution. I was trying to assign some values to a list , created a viewmodel and then passed the values in the ViewModel to the View from the controller.

The problem is it quite displays the list but it ONLY displays the last item in the list (Tirus Peters) six times, instead of displaying other items in the list. I do not know what i did wrong.

These are my code:

The Model:

```
namespace Learning.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public double Salary { get; set; }

        public Employee(int eID, string first, string Last, double sal)
        {
            this.EmployeeID = eID;
            this.FirstName = first;
            this.LastName = Last;
            this.Salary = sal;
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel :

```
namespace Learning.ViewModel
{
    public class EmloyeeViewModel
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }                
        public string Salary { get; set; }
        public string salcolor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Index Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EmloyeeViewModel em = new EmloyeeViewModel();
            List<EmloyeeViewModel> emVM = new List<EmloyeeViewModel>();
            List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>()
            {
             new Employee(1, "Tony", "Cruise", 231.89),
             new Employee(2, "Bill", "George", 152.11),
             new Employee(3, "John", "Bill", 7651.29),
             new Employee(4, "Donald", "Kay", 1500.08),
             new Employee(5, "Smith", "Bill", 28.91),
             new Employee(6, "Tirus", "Peter", 1128.91)

             };

            foreach (Employee f in emp)
            {
                em.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID;
                em.FullName = f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName;
                em.Salary = f.Salary.ToString("C");
                if (f.Salary > 100)
                {
                  em.salcolor = "green";
                }else
                {
                  em.salcolor = "red";
                }
                emVM.Add(em);

            }

            return View(emVM);
    }
}
```

The Index View:

```
@using Learning.ViewModel
    @model IList<EmloyeeViewModel>

    <h2>Got It!!</h2>

    <table>

        <tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>Full Name</th><th>Salary</th></tr>

     @foreach (var a in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@a.EmployeeID</td>
            <td>@a.FullName</td>
            <td><span style="background-color:@a.salcolor">@a.Salary</span></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You're adding the same object, you should `new` it after each insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inserted the `EmployeeViewModel` object, you were inserting the same object with the same reference again and again since you construct just one object outside the `foreach` loop. So your list will contain items all of them will have the same values of the last item iterated through in the `foreach` loop as they share the same reference `foreach` loop was in fact applying new values on the same object which is basically all items in the `List`

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<EmloyeeViewModel> emVM = new List<EmloyeeViewModel>();
            List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>()
            {
             new Employee(1, "Tony", "Cruise", 231.89),
             new Employee(2, "Bill", "George", 152.11),
             new Employee(3, "John", "Bill", 7651.29),
             new Employee(4, "Donald", "Kay", 1500.08),
             new Employee(5, "Smith", "Bill", 28.91),
             new Employee(6, "Tirus", "Peter", 1128.91)

             };

            foreach (Employee f in emp)
            {
                EmloyeeViewModel em = new EmloyeeViewModel();
                em.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID;
                em.FullName = f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName;
                em.Salary = f.Salary.ToString("C");
                if (f.Salary > 100)
                {
                    em.salcolor = "green";
                }
                else
                {
                    em.salcolor = "red";
                }
                emVM.Add(em);

            }

            return View(emVM);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing....what can I do without you guys!!. Stackoverflow is certainly my new home. Many thanks to the pro in the house. Someday, I hope I can be at least close to your expertise. You solved it!!..but please let me ask this/ which of this is ok to use:  EmloyeeViewModel em = new EmloyeeViewModel(); OR  em = new EmployeeViewModel();. Both work but which will you advise I stick to. Many thanks once again

Comment: Since you don't want to access `em` outside the `foreach` scope. There is no need to declare it outside. But both are correct.

Comment: Thanks so much. I felt like i won a gold. Its been a struggle. Thanks for your patience. It was just a self-imposed academic exercise but I have learnt a lot. May you be rewarded for your kindness. Thank you for sharing a piece of your knowledge so patiently and professionally!!

Comment: Also a good note is that the viewmodel salcolor should be a property directly on the viewmodel.  Otherwise you have to repeat your a code for the reuse the model in another method/controller.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are adding the same object to your list 6 times. You will need to create a new instance of `EmployeeViewModel` each iteration. See code below.

```
foreach (Employee f in emp)
{
    // Create a new instance for each item.
    em = new EmployeeViewModel();

    em.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID;
    em.FullName = f.FirstName + " " + f.LastName;
    em.Salary = f.Salary.ToString("C");
    if (f.Salary > 100)
    {
        em.salcolor = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        em.salcolor = "red";
    }
    emVM.Add(em);
}
```